# Find color blending function from partially known input and output

Tags: graphics, colors

I have a set of known destination (background) colors and known output colors for some blending function for some constant source color, but I don't know the source color or the function.

As you can see in the image below, there doesn't seem to be full correlation between hues. Destinations on the left are sorted in order of hue, output colors are clearly not. This suggests that the R,G,B channels are not handled independently.

I know that all these destination-output pairs are using the same function and source color, so how would I go about solving? Using a color palette is not suitable as the given set is only a close approximation.

The blend function will be implemented programmatically, but the solution from these unknowns can be either manual or programmatic for my purposes.

[Image of given set, destination on the left, output on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBIVE.png)

RGB values:

```
Source            Output
255, 145, 139     237, 139, 131
236, 197, 189     218, 133, 149
217, 195, 42      197, 131, 93
89,  175, 141     58,  135, 90
98,  167, 195     106, 115, 143
111, 169, 193     58,  128, 91
72,  132, 161     76,  115, 139
121, 130, 196     120, 125, 158
99,  104, 167     100, 124, 149
132, 133, 147     131, 126, 135
99,  100, 116     109, 128, 127
66,  63,  79      85,  131, 121
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you mean each colour on the left becomes the corresponding colour on the right at the same level? If so, both green and black on the left seem to map to a similar green on the right! Do you have the colour values as two lists of RGB triplets rather than as images?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yep you got it. I'll add the lists to the main post later. They're not going to be exact values though, as I sampled them from a rendered video file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added them

Comment: I've spoken briefly to the illustrator of my source video, they say that the effect was actually done by the person editing. This inplies that this color set is almost definitely computed rather than chosen. However, I don't see how two similar inputs can give such different outputs (lines 5 and 6)... I have found a possible alternative solution for my case but this question still remains. Although, maybe it would be better suited to an art forum.